# How do I make the .vscode/setting.json to stop being in my side window

Tags: visual-studio-code

Every time I open VSCode I see this `.vscode/setting.json`. i tried deleting it but I don't know how to make it go away for good

[image]

I tried to delete it but it kept appearing in my window.

Comment: show a screenshot with more context and describe the context in words.

Comment: It is completely normal for vs code to contain a setting.json file like this.

Comment: look inside what settings it contains, then disable the source of these settings, most likely it is YOU